# Using second method to get the average of an Array

Tags: arrays, methods, average

I am trying to implement two methods: a `main` method and another side method. The side method does the math to get the average of the Array, which is located in the main method itself. It then returns it to the main method.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayAverageDouble
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double average=0;
        int i=0;
        double sum=0;
        int size = 0;

        System.out.println("What size do you want the Array: ");
        size = sc.nextInt();

        double arrayDouble[] = new double[size];

        for (i = 0; i < arrayDouble.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            arrayDouble[i]=sc.nextDouble();
        }

       System.out.println("The average of ' arrayDouble ' is: " + average);

        sc.close();
    }

    private static void avgInt(double[] arrayDouble)
    {
        average = ?
        return average;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static double average(double[] arrayDouble) {
    double total = 0;
    for(double value : arrayDouble) {
        total += value;
    } 
    return total / arrarDouble.lenght;
}
```

Comment: HI there thanks for the fast reply, I cleaned your code a little bit but still I only get 0.0 as average no matter what I enter... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, add `average = average(arrayDouble);` before printing the result.

Comment: 'average = avgInt(arrayDouble);'
I think I fixed it finally, changed the second average with the name of my method (avgInt) and now it is working flawlessly, thanks a ton, all the best <3

Comment: Remember to upvote and/or accept Sander's answer if it was useful to you!

Comment: @MrsAskeAlot Yeah, in the code above I changed `avgInt() ` to `average()`, because it has nothing to do with an int.

Comment: That's just silly by me, I understand thanks again and chose your answer as correct one since I can't upvote. Thanks again ^^